# Match a list of IP addresses in a compressed log file

Tags: python-3.x, gzip

I need to find a match to a list of IP Addresses(464k) from some (74k) of our compressed log files. When I decompress them manually and search them my script works, however, I don't have matches when the files are compressed.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import gzip

realList=open('ipList', 'r')
testlist=open('testList', 'r')
offender=open('offenders', 'w')
# DEV Log Dir Uncompressed #
logDir = 'ulogs'

# DEV Log Dir Compressed #
#logDir = 'clogs'

logFile=[ logFiles for logFiles in listdir(logDir) if isfile(join(logDir, logFiles))]
count=0

with testlist as host:
  ips = set(l.strip() for l in host)
  for lfile in logFile:
    print(lfile)
    # Uncompressed # Results: 870,328 Hits
    with open(logDir + '/' + lfile, 'r') as log:
    # Compressed # Results: 0 Hits
    #with gzip.open(logDir + '/' + lfile, 'r') as log:
      for line in log:
        #print(line)
        elements = line.split()
        if ips.intersection(elements):
          #print(elements[3])
          offender.write(elements[3] + '\n');
          count+=1
    print(count)
```